# How to determine when module was completely loaded in debian?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian

I need to know when module was completely loaded.
`lsmod` and `modinfo` haven't had necessary info.
Which log has that info?

Answer (score 0):

Actually lsmod (or /proc/modules, which is equivalent) should show the module in the list if it was successfully loaded.  If it is not there, assume it was not loaded successfully.

Comment: But that's just a fact of successfully\unsuccessfully loading. But when it was done, I can not keep track.

Comment: Apologies, I understood "when" to mean "if" in your question.  Most modules will print something to the kernel log, and the system logger should timestamp that.  But I can't immediately think of a systematic way to check.

Comment: Modules are loaded via user space helper. The helper (udev) call a system call for that. I dunno if it's synchronous or asynchronous. In any case fact of successful doesn't mean that module is working.